# Highlight and copy code from jsfiddle

Tags: jsfiddle

is it possible to select and copy code I've written in jsfiddle?
When I try to select code (Chrome 28.0, Mac OSX), the text get deselected as soon as I release the mouseclick (quasi onmouseup).

Sorry if there is already a similar question, but it's hard to google jsfiddle related problems.

Comment: No problem here with Firefox 25 (alpha) and never see that before with older Firefox version.

Comment: Hmm... Yes, I just have this problem with chrome.

Comment: Works fine on Chrome too, but with Windows... Is there any other MAC user in the assistance to help this poor guy? :-)

Comment: I'm using Firefox 24.0 on Windows 7, and the problem is also happening with me.
-- edit --
The error seems to be sporadic; sometimes it happens, sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: Using Chrome 32.0 on Mac 10.6.8 and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with Firefox 28 but I found the solution is to click in whichever box you want the code from to get the cursor and then click control+a (windows - select all shortcut) then control+c (windows - copy shortcut). If you don't want all the code just paste it into notepad and then copy whichever portion you desire.

Answer (score 0):

Simply: press Run before copying.

Highlighting doesn't work when something is done in result pane of jsfiddle screen (e.g. when I press a button). To make highlighting work again is necessary to get the screen to its initial state by pressing "Run" or "Update" (tiddy and fork probably work as well).